# Is there a Perl regex metacharacter or a way to have specify a default value, if a subpattern capture does not match?

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

Here's the idea. I am parsing command line options but doing it across the entire command line, not by each @ARGV element separately.

```
program --format="%H:%M:%S" --timeout 12 --nofail
```

I want the parsing to work with these cases.

1. **--name=value**, easy to parse
2. **--name value,** pretty easy
3. **--name no value**, default the value to 1

Here is the regex which works, except it cannot do the missing value case

```
%options = "@ARGV" ~= /--([A-Za-z]+)[= ]([^-]\S*)/g;
```

i.e. match **--name=value** or **--name value** but not **--name --name**, --name --name is two names, not a --name=value pair.

If a **--name** has no value following it that matches the second capture in the regex, is there a way, within the regex, to specify a default, in my case a 1, to indicate "true". i.e. if an --name has no argument, like **--nofail** then set that argument to 1 indicating true.

Actually, in asking this I figured out a workaround using separate match statements which is fine. However, just out of curiosity, the question still stands, is there a Perl regex way to have a default if a submatch fails?

Comment: No. Regex is a matching expression. It doesn’t “do” anything to the input, especially creating characters that weren’t in the input. You’re going to have to use code for this.

Comment: Sure there's a way; most of the time there is some way.  (But, there are libraries for this, and it'd be easier to parse it normally.)  (1) Do you, for some reason, really insist on doing it by regex?  (2) Must it be *all* done inside one regex?

Comment: Your approach will break badly on something like `program --format='%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' --timeout 12 --nofail`, where one of the arguments contains a space. Instead of joining all arguments into a single string, you should process them using a loop.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how to return a list reflecting a changed input from a regex alone. To change the input we need `s{}{}er` operator, as we need code in its replacement part to analyze captures and decide what to change; and, we get a string, not a list, which need be further processed (split).

Here is then one such take, with a minimal intrusion of code.

Match `name` and `value`, with `=` or space between them, and if `value` (`$2`) is undefined give it a value; so we need `/e` to implement that.<sup>†</sup> Once we are at it, put a space between all name-value pairs. This goes under `/r` so that the changed string is returned, and passed through `split`

```
my %arg = split ' ', 
    $args =~ s{ --(\w+) (?: =|\s+|\z) ([^-]\S*)? }{ $1.' '.($2//'7 ') }ergx;
```

The `split` can be done by another regex instead but that's still extra processing.

A complete program (with more flags added to the input)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $args = shift // q(--fmt="%H:%M" --f1 --time 12 --f2 --f3);      
say $args;

my %arg = split ' ',
   $args =~ s{ --(\w+) (?: =|\s+|\z) ([^-]\S*)? }{ $1 . ' ' . ($2//'1 ') }ergx; 

say "$_ => $arg{$_}" for keys %arg;
```

This prints as expected.  But note that there may be edge cases, and in particular having a space inside (a quoted) argument value, like `"%H %M"`, would require a far more complex pattern.

I presume that the regex ask is for play/study. Normally this goes by libraries, like [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long).  If that is somehow not possible then processing `@ARGV` term by term is nice and easy -- and *fast*.

---

<sup>†</sup> In order to actually do "*if `value` (`$2`) is undefined give it a value*" we need to run code in the replacement part, what is done under the `/e` modifier